# Buttons Overlap

Tags: android, button, chronometer

I made a stopwatch using chronometer with four buttons but when i use the visibility modes to make stop and pause button appear they overlap.... Pls explain why...Below is the code.....

Assume the layout file with buttons in relative layout...

```
public class StopWatchFragment extends Fragment {

Chronometer chronometer;
Button startStopWatch;
Button stopStopWatch;
Button resetStopWatch;
Button pauseStopWatch;
Button resumeStopWatch;
private long lastPause;
//RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
private int check = 0;

public StopWatchFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stopwatch_layout,container,false);
chronometer = (Chronometer) rootView.findViewById(R.id.stopwatch);
startStopWatch = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.startStopWatch);
stopStopWatch = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.stopStopWatch);
resetStopWatch = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.resetStopWatch);
pauseStopWatch = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pauseStopWatch);
resumeStopWatch = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.resumeStopWatch);
relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.parentRelativeLayout);
pauseStopWatch.setVisibility(View.GONE);

//final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(relativeLayout.getLayoutParams());

startStopWatch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        chronometer.start();
        startStopWatch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        pauseStopWatch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if(check == 1){
            resumeStopWatch.setClickable(true);
        }
        else{
            resumeStopWatch.setClickable(false);
        }
        //params.setMargins(16,16,16,16);
        //pauseStopWatch.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
});

pauseStopWatch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        check = 1;
        lastPause = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        chronometer.stop();
    }
});

resumeStopWatch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        chronometer.setBase(chronometer.getBase() + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - lastPause);
        chronometer.start();
        resumeStopWatch.setClickable(false);
    }
});

stopStopWatch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        chronometer.stop();
        startStopWatch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        pauseStopWatch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        resumeStopWatch.setClickable(false);
    }
});

resetStopWatch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        chronometer.stop();
        resumeStopWatch.setClickable(false);
        startStopWatch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        pauseStopWatch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});

return rootView;
}
}
```

This is the layout file pls refer for this....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/parentRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <Chronometer
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:id="@+id/stopwatch"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/stopwatch">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/startStopWatch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Start"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/pauseStopWatch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Pause"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/stopStopWatch"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/startStopWatch"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
                android:text="Stop"
                android:textSize="24sp"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/resetStopWatch"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
                android:text="Reset"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/resumeStopWatch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
                android:text="Resume"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/resetStopWatch"/>


        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

[This is the way buttons work when click on start button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kqyC.jpg)

Comment: post you layout xml file

Comment: Posted the layout file ... pls answer now...

Answer (score 0):

You are hiding the button, but you are still listening with the OnClickListener. Try adding:

```
pauseStopWatch.setOnClickListener(null);
```

Then, when you make your button visible:

```
pauseStopWatch.setOnClickListener(whatever);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:id="@+id/parentRelativeLayout"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

<Chronometer
  android:layout_centerInParent="true"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textSize="30sp"
  android:textAlignment="center"
  android:id="@+id/stopwatch"
  android:layout_margin="16dp"/>

<ScrollView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_below="@id/stopwatch">
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
      <Button
          android:id="@+id/startStopWatch"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Start"
          android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
          android:textSize="24sp" />

      <Button
          android:visibility="gone"
          android:id="@+id/pauseStopWatch"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Pause"
          android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
          android:textSize="24sp" />

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/stopStopWatch"
          android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_below="@id/startStopWatch"
          android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
          android:text="Stop"
          android:textSize="24sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
      <Button
          android:id="@+id/resetStopWatch"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
          android:text="Reset"
          android:textSize="24sp" />

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/resumeStopWatch"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
          android:text="Resume"
          android:textSize="24sp"
          android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:layout_below="@id/resetStopWatch"/>


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

In the above, the `pause` button will be set to `Gone`. You make it visible later when user clicks `start` button